# Mapping one hash value to other hash ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash which gives me the data in following manner:

```
details = [{"severity_longevity" => "Medium", "operating_leverage" => "High",
        "financial_leverage"=> "Low", "revenue_growth"=> "Low"}]

I have one hash which gives me the score that I am supposed to assign.
```

score = [{"Low"=> 5},{"Medium"=> 10}, {"High"=> 15}]

How can I change the "Medium" "Low" and "High" in `details` hash with their number scores from 
`score` hash ?

Comment: `details` and `score` aren't a `Hash`, but array of hashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hashes you can use `transform_values` method

```
details = {
  "severity_longevity" => "Medium", 
  "operating_leverage" => "High",
  "financial_leverage"=> "Low", 
  "revenue_growth"=> "Low"
}
score = {"Low" => 5, "Medium" => 10, "High" => 15}

updated = details.transform_values { |v| score[v] }
# => { "severity_longevity" => 10, ... }
```